# Why did I get a remote debugging request?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, remote-debugging

While I was debugging a program in Visual Studio 2010, a dialog box popped up and asked whether I wanted to open up the firewall because of a remote debugging request.

Does this mean a person has initiated this request?

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

This means that you are trying to debug a Method which belongs to an assembly on another machine (Another PC / Server / Device / ...)

Remote Debugging in Visual Studio

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx